# Object Selection: Select More/Less

Tags: select

I don't understand how **Select ‣ More/Less ‣ Less** operator works.
On the manual it says this,

> Contrast the selection, deselect objects at the boundaries of parent/child relationships.

But this is vague and unintuitive. Would you mind providing more concrete explanation?

By the way, do you use these operators often?

Comment: If you select an object, you can quickly select its children or parent with Select More (shortcut Ctrl + and - to select less)

Comment: There are more implications because 'Select Less' isn't doing the polar opposite of 'Select More'

Comment: Il looks like Select Less will deselect, from parent to children

Comment: @moonboots It's kinda weird.

Comment: It works really weird ... https://imgur.com/qnDbDrs ... and order selection doesn't make a difference.